# Android MediaPlayer IOException

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm writing a program in which I need to play a song from storage.  I set up a MediaPlayer for this (code fragment below), but kept getting a java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1.  Some websites indicated that this error may occur because the files I am trying to read are not world readable.  If this is true, how could I change the file permissions from the program, get around this, or some other solution.  If not, please help me figure out what is wrong with this.  Thanks in advance.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.reset();
player.setDataSource(selectedFilePath);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where are you attempting to read the files from? It's possible that you're looking at the /sdcard/ area, and your application does not have the ability to read_external_storage

If that is the case, just make sure you add the following line to your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

[Edit]
I'm not sure where you're trying to load from, but it might help to use a descriptor instead of a path. See if this helps:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(locationOfFile);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
```

If this still doesn't help, I would recommend trying another file name to make sure your media player setup is correct. Or you can do something like

```
File thisFile = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Music/song.mp3");
if (thisFile.exists())
   Log.v("file", "Exists");
else
   Log.v("file", "Could not be located.");
```

Comment: The path is "/storage/sdcard0/Music/song.mp3."  It is internal memory, although it does seem to be marked as an sdcard.  I added that to the manifest, but still no luck.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why `FileInputStream` is more reliable, than just passing the path into `setDataSource`, but it works, so thank you.